# Unbind .onselectstart return false

Tags: javascript, dom-events, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am trying to write a userscript that will remove the effects of `onselectstart` from an id on a page.

So far I am assuming that I can rebind the original function using something like this:

```
document.getElementById('nodrag').onselectstart = function() { /* code original action */ };
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onmylemon/V3SAt/)

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to do something before/after the original selectStart function? It's not totally clear to me. If so, you can store the old selectStart event handler and call it wherever you want inside the new selectStart handler.

Comment: Hi LightStyle, this would be after. The script I am writing will be a userscript (greasemonkey) and will allow the selection of text on a page where the creator of the page has tried to not allow it. Thanks.

Comment: Wrap your function inside `window.onload`, it should work

Comment: Thanks, it appears that isn't doing it either. What I am looking for is some code that will bring back the ability to select text. http://jsfiddle.net/onmylemon/V3SAt/2/

Comment: Have you any possibilities to load the script at the end of the page? If you can, you can also don't wrap the code in window.onload and leave the line as it is(try this just in JSFiddle, in "framework and extensions" on the left select "no wrap - in `<body>`" instead of "onload"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I managed to work out the answer. Thank you LightStyle for giving me the hints.

So I create an script tag with `document.getElementById('nodrag').onselectstart = function() {  };` inside it and append this to the body.

```
// Create the script to remove the nodrag from chrome
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.innerHTML = "document.getElementById('nodrag').onselectstart = function() {  };";
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild(script);
```

This might not work in traditional contexts however works a charm on a userscript. Here is the final script:

https://gist.github.com/lgoldstien/5928021

Comment: I asked how to make it to work with `body` tag too `<body onselectstart="return false" onload="">`  , and I was able to disable it now with this     `script.innerHTML = "document.getElementsBytagName('body')[0].onselectstart = function() {  };";`